# Word count for The whole project on scrivener.?

Tags: scrivener, wordcount

I know I can see the word count for each chapter at the bottom on my scrivener page but I cannot seem to find where I can keep track of the word count for the whole book i am working on. Can someone tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project ---> Project statistics.